# u_mass and c_npmi, the coherence score methods of topic modeling

Tags: lda, topic-modeling

I have a question about the coherence measurement method of topic modeling.
I saw the reference that it is better not to use c_vhttps://palmetto.demos.dice-research.org, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/406216/what-is-the-formula-for-c-v-coherence. So I'm going to measure the coherence using u_mass and c_npmi.

My question is, I heard that the lower the coherence score measured by u_mass, the better, so is k corresponding to the lowest coherence score the optimal number of topics?

In the case of the coherence score measured by c_npmi, is the higher the better? If so, is k with a high coherence score measured by c_npmi the optimal number of topics?

I am studying the coherence score method necessary for topic modeling. Seeing that there is a negative correlation between c_v and other methods made me curious. So I got curious about "u_mass" and "c_npmi", but I'm honestly confused. I'd appreciate it if you could answer me kindly.